# How do I load android 2.3.4 onto my dev phone?

Tags: hardware, rom

So, I have an original Droid (rooted), that is also my working cell phone. Can I load 2.3.4 onto it to develop accessory apps?

If so how do I load the new OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option (probably the easiest) would be to install CyanogenMod on your phone. I don't recall offhand if the latest stable release (7.0.3) is based on 2.3.4 or 2.3.3, but you could certainly use a nightly build instead which would be 2.3.4. The forums for the Droid can be found [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/forum/13-motorola-droid/), and they have a section for stable builds and a section for nightly builds that you can take a look at.

For detailed instructions on how to prepare and install CyanogenMod, the best resource is [their wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Motorola_Droid%3a_Full_Update_Guide).

Comment: I know this is an old question now, but I cannot get CyanogenMod to load any rom. It's already rooted and loaded CM just fine, but it won't load the downloadable roms or from the sdcard.

Comment: @Eric: Do you mean ClockworkMod? Are you getting any failure messages? Are you trying to flash the ROM via the recovery menu or via the ROM Manager app?

Comment: In **ROM Manager v4.2.1.0** Under **ROM Management** I've tried either **Install ROM from SD Card** or **Download ROM** and no matter what I pick it reboots too the triangle next to a phone

Comment: @Eric: Sounds like the custom recovery (ClockworkMod) is not installed. [This thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/7056-droid-reboottriangle-pic/) suggests either reflashing ClockworkMod from ROM manager or following the SPRecovery instructions from the wiki page (linked above in my answer).

Comment: Turns out after a factory reset with wiping data/partition/etc. it loaded. Without paying for it I get 2.3.3...